# Draft.js <Editor/> won't react if clicking on 'blank space'.

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/Op8BoLzQ

If you click on the first line, the editor cursor will show, but if you click on blank space below, nothing will happen.

I've tried to set min-height to height, now it is acting correctly regarding this issue, but the content is not auto-resizable anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The problem is that the part of the editor that's contentEditable is only one line right now, here's a screenshot to illustrate which part of the editor is the dom node with `contentEditable` set to true.

[image]

Instead, if you want to make the area of the editable interface larger, you need to style `.public-DraftEditor-content`

[I've forked the sandbox to show this](https://codesandbox.io/s/2kjMmQnqK)

That fixes the issue.